# How can I fix this angular memory leak?

Tags: angularjs, memory-leaks

Here's my js

```
var app = angular.module('SearchAndResultsApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
app.controller('SearchAndResultsController', function($location ,$scope, $http){
$scope.fields = [
    { id: 'accountNumber', name: 'Account Number', clicked: false},
    { id: 'pointOfInterestName', name: 'Point Of Interest Name', clicked: true},
    { id: 'address1', name: 'Address 1', clicked: false},
    { id: 'address2', name: 'Address 2', clicked: false},
    { id: 'city', name: 'City', clicked: false},
    { id: 'isostateCode', name: 'ISO State Code', clicked: false},
    { id: 'postalCode', name: 'Postal Code', clicked: false},
    { id: 'phone', name: 'Phone', clicked: false},
    { id: 'fax', name: 'Fax', clicked: false},
    { id: 'website', name: 'Website', clicked: false},
    { id: 'email', name: 'Email', clicked: false},
    { id: 'isocountryCode', name: 'ISO Country Code', clicked: false},
    { id: 'latitude', name: 'Latitude', clicked: false},
    { id: 'longitude', name: 'Longitude', clicked: false}
];

$scope.getSearchState = function() {
    var fields = window.location.hash.substring(1).split("&");
    if (fields.length > 0) {
        return decodeURIComponent(fields[0]);
    } else {
        return '';
    }
};

$scope.getPageState = function() {
    var fields = window.location.hash.substring(1).split("&");
    if (fields.length > 1) {
        return parseInt(fields[1]);
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
};

$scope.noResults = false;
$scope.pointsOfInterest = null;
$scope.loadingQuery = false;
$scope.orderDirection = 'asc';
$scope.glyphDirection = 'glyphicon-triangle-top';
$scope.orderedBy = 'pointOfInterestName';
$scope.previousClicked = $scope.fields[1];
$scope.lowerRange = 0;
$scope.upperRange = 0;
$scope.totalRange = 0;
$scope.currentPage = $scope.getPageState();
$scope.searchString = $scope.getSearchState();
$scope.offset = 'col-sm-offset-4';
$scope.loadingOffset = 'col-sm-offset-1';

$scope.getResultsState = function() {
  return ((($scope.pointsOfInterest == null)||($scope.pointsOfInterest[0] == null)) && ($scope.searchString != ''))
};

$scope.downloadCSV = function(selection) {
    if (selection == 'searched') {
        window.location = 'pointsOfInterest/' + encodeURIComponent($scope.searchString) + '/orderedList/' + $scope.orderedBy + '/' + $scope.orderDirection + '/csv';
    } else if (selection == 'all') {
        if (confirm("This may take some time.")){
            window.location = 'allPointsOfInterest/csv';
        }
    }
};

$scope.updateRanges = function() {
    $scope.searchString = $scope.searchString = $scope.searchString.replace(/\//g,'').replace(/\\/g,'');
    window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent($scope.searchString) + '&' + encodeURIComponent($scope.currentPage);
    if ($scope.pointsOfInterest[0] != null) {
        $scope.lowerRange = ($scope.currentPage - 1) * 20 + 1;
        $scope.totalRange = $scope.pointsOfInterest.length;
        $scope.upperRange = $scope.currentPage * 20;
    } else {
        $scope.lowerRange = 0;
        $scope.totalRange = 0;
        $scope.upperRange = 0;
    }
    if ($scope.upperRange > $scope.totalRange) {
        $scope.upperRange = $scope.totalRange;
    }
};

$scope.updateGlyphs = function(field) {
    $scope.searchString = $scope.searchString = $scope.searchString.replace(/\//g,'').replace(/\\/g,'');
    $scope.orderedBy = field.id;

    if ($scope.previousClicked != null)
        $scope.previousClicked.clicked = false;
    field.clicked = true;

    if ($scope.previousClicked == field) {
        if ($scope.orderDirection == 'asc') {
            $scope.orderDirection = 'desc';
            $scope.glyphDirection = 'glyphicon-triangle-bottom';
        } else {
            $scope.orderDirection = 'asc';
            $scope.glyphDirection = 'glyphicon-triangle-top';
        }
    } else {
         $scope.orderDirection = 'asc';
         $scope.glyphDirection = 'glyphicon-triangle-top';
    }

    $scope.updatePointsOfInterest();

    $scope.previousClicked = field;
};

$scope.updatePointsOfInterest = function() {
    if ($scope.searchString.length != 0) {
        $scope.loadingOffset = '';
        $scope.currentPage = $scope.getPageState();
        $scope.searchString = $scope.searchString.replace(/\//g,'').replace(/\\/g,'');
        window.location.hash = encodeURIComponent($scope.searchString) + '&' + encodeURIComponent($scope.currentPage);
        if ($scope.searchString == '') return;
        $scope.loadingQuery = true;
        $http.get('pointsOfInterest/' + encodeURIComponent($scope.searchString) + '/orderedList/' + $scope.orderedBy + '/' + $scope.orderDirection)
            .success(function(data) {
                $scope.pointsOfInterest = data;
                $scope.loadingQuery = false;
                $scope.loadingOffset = 'col-sm-offset-1';
                $scope.updateRanges();
                $scope.noResults = $scope.getResultsState();
                if ($scope.pointsOfInterest.length > 0) {
                    $scope.offset = '';
                } else {
                    $scope.offset = 'col-sm-offset-4';
                }
            })
            .error(function(data) {
                window.location = 'pointsOfInterest/' + encodeURIComponent($scope.searchString) + '/orderedList/' + $scope.orderedBy + '/' + $scope.orderDirection;
            });
    }
};

window.onhashchange = function() {
    $scope.updatePointsOfInterest();
}
$scope.updatePointsOfInterest();

$scope.gotoUpdatePage = function (accountNumber) {
    window.location.href = 'pointOfInterestEditor/' + accountNumber;
};

$scope.onTextClick = function ($event) {
    $event.target.select();
};
});
app.directive('ngDelay', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope: true,
    compile: function (element, attributes) {
        var expression = attributes['ngChange'];
        if (!expression)
            return;

        var ngModel = attributes['ngModel'];
        if (ngModel) attributes['ngModel'] = '$parent.' + ngModel;
        attributes['ngChange'] = '$$delay.execute()';

        return {
            post: function (scope, element, attributes) {
                scope.$$delay = {
                    expression: expression,
                    delay: scope.$eval(attributes['ngDelay']),
                    execute: function () {
                        var state = scope.$$delay;
                        state.then = Date.now();
                        $timeout(function () {
                            if (Date.now() - state.then >= state.delay)
                                scope.$parent.$eval(expression);
                        }, state.delay);
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
};
}]);
```

I get a memory leak from adding in the $location to the controller. I would like to use $location instead of window.location. I'm not sure why the memory leak is caused. Anyone know why and how to fix it?

Edit: It appears to be making infinite get requests. Still not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all `$location` service has a `hash()` method that u can use instead of `window.location.hash()`.

Second: you call `$scope.updatePointsOfInterest()` method on your controller load that do a http get request. If it fails it changes the url. When the url is changed your controller code is reloaded, hence `$scope.updatePointsOfInterest()` method is executing again and again.

I'm not sure why `$http.error()` method is triggered. It could be anything. Check out your XHR request in Network tab in dev tools (Chrome).

If your `$http.error()` method should fail (this means that there's an error and it's properly handled) than to fix the "infinite looping" issue you can do the following:
1) either doesn't call `$scope.updatePointsOfInterest()` on controller loading
2) or doesn't change the url in your `$http.error()` method

If you describe what you're trying to achieve with this `updatePointsOfInterest()` method I will be able to help you write it properly.

Regards,
Aleksey

Comment: updatePointsOfInterest() performs a get which is handled in a controller where a sql query is performed that returns a list of points of interest.

Comment: So, by writting $scope.updatePointsOfInterest() method directly in the controller you're loading the initial data? If the answer is yes, than you're doing it wrong. It should be done in the router with resolve property. Check out this article for example: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx 
If you don't want to familiarize yourself with "resolves" and make a quick fix, you can write 2 separate methods: one for loading initial data set and another for updating it. And in the first one don't do a redirect